# Trying to make a mailer fire to specific users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, boolean-logic

Trying to make a mailer fire to all users if none of these booleans are true.  If any of them are true, we are trying to make the mailer fire only to the those users who's `sports` match the true boolean (ex: an article with a .football that equals true will send an email to those users who's sport = "Football")

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save

    if (@article.football && @article.basketball && @article.volleyball && @article.lacrosse) == false
       all_users = User.all
       all_users.each do |user|
        ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)
      end

    elsif @article.football == true 
        User.where( :sport => "Football").each do |user|
          ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)
      end

    elsif @article.basketball == true    
      User.where("users.sport LIKE ?", "%Basketball%").each do |user|
        ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)
      end

    elsif @article.volleyball == true 
      User.where( :sport => "Volleyball").each do |user|
        ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)
      end

    elsif @article.lacrosse == true 
      User.where( :sport => "Lacrosse").each do |user|
        ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)
      end


    end

    # send email to referral email
      # @allusers.each do |user|
      # ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,Article.find(5)) 
   redirect_to @article
    else
     render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Why won't all users be emailed if all four of those booleans are false?  It's currently not firing when all four are false

Comment: because your not telling it to anywhere. Looks like your first condition which you are expecting to evaluate to `false` is wrong.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you create a Sport model and associate it to both User and Article?  Then you can just cut out the middle man and get the users by running `@article.sport.users`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use an `else` block in this case. Because that is what else means: non of the conditions before were true

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    users = if @article.football 
              User.where(:sport => "Football")
            elsif @article.basketball
              User.where("users.sport LIKE ?", "%Basketball%")
            elsif @article.volleyball
              User.where(:sport => "Volleyball")
            elsif @article.lacrosse
              User.where(:sport => "Lacrosse")
            else
              User.all
            end

    users.each do |user|
      ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user, @article)
    end

    redirect_to @article

  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Furthermore I suggest to move that logic into the model. That would make it easier to maintain and to test:

```
# in models/artikel.rb
def notify_users
  users_interested_in_this_article.each do |user|
    ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user, @article)
  end
end

private

def users_interested_in_this_article
  if football 
    User.where(:sport => "Football")
  elsif basketball
    User.where("users.sport LIKE ?", "%Basketball%")
  elsif volleyball
    User.where(:sport => "Volleyball")
  elsif lacrosse
    User.where(:sport => "Lacrosse")
  else
    User.all
  end
end

# in the controller
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    @article.notify_users
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the truthyness wrong.

I would change

```
if (@article.football && @article.basketball && @article.volleyball && @article.lacrosse) == false
```

to something like this

```
if @artical.football == false and @article.basketball == false and ... and ...
```

Or better yet

```
if [@article.football,@article.basketball,@article.volleyball,@article.lacrosse].all? { |x| x == false }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked for and it sent for one article being true but when multiple article are true, it only sends to the first .sport in the method (for example: if .volleyball and .lacrosse were both true, only the volleyball coaches would get emailed

Comment: We still can't email more than one set of users (volleyball and football) if more than one is true.  We need to be able to email, for example, all the volleyball and football users if both of those booleans are true - the method is only executing the first attribute that equals true.

Answer (score 0):

The code here

```
if (@article.football && @article.basketball && @article.volleyball && @article.lacrosse) == false
```

means `if ( Any one is false ) == false`.

What you are trying to do is:

```
if ( !@article.football && !@article.basketball && !@article.volleyball && !@article.lacrosse )
   all_users = User.all
   all_users.each do |user|
    ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)
  end
end
```